# list of boto3 queries only return the last result

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

As I have configured multiple profile in .aws/credentials file. I need to read a file that contains a list of keys to be used as parameter in boto3 dynamodb query.
So my code looks like this:

```
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key

def query_keys(dynamodb, bucketAndKey):
    table = dynamodb.Table('media-import-address')
    response = table.query(
        KeyConditionExpression=Key('bucketAndKey').eq(bucketAndKey)
    )
    return response['Items']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    file_name = input("Enter your file name: ")
    dynamodb = boto3.Session(profile_name='prod-cn').resource('dynamodb')
    with open(file_name) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            result = query_keys(dynamodb, line)
            print(result)
```

My input file is a plain text file which looks like this:
aaa/abc.jpg
aaa/bbb.png
abc/aa.gif

The running result looks this:

```
[]
[]
[{'seq': Decimal('2'), 'schemaVersion': Decimal('1'), 'media': 'MDAVD'}]
```

Why the previous 2 not get executed?

Answer (score 1):

A probable reason is that your `line` will include new line character (i.e. `\n`). Thus it will search for `bucketAndKey` with the `\n` at the end.

To remove the `\n` from the line, you can check the following:

```
result = query_keys(dynamodb, line.rstrip())
```